# How to create an Excel file and it by Email, using code x++ in Dynamics AX2012?

Tags: email, axapta, email-attachments, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to create an Excel file and to send it by Email, by X++ code in to Dyncamics AX2012.
If it's possible I don't want to save the data in a physical path/folder.

I wrote this code, but after I need to send the Excel.

I would like to follow the D365 instructions (https://axexplorer.wordpress.com/2017/07/18/create-an-excel-file-and-send-it-through-e-mail-in-d365-for-operationax-7/ )in *Dynamics AX 2012* (In AX2012 some command are not available)

```
SysEmailParameters parameters = SysEmailParameters::find();
SMTPRelayServerName relayServer;
SMTPPortNumber portNumber;
SMTPUserName userName;
SMTPPassword password;
Str1260 subject,body;
InteropPermission interopPermission;
SysMailerMessageBuilder  mailer;
SysMailerAttachments attach;
System.Exception e;

SysExcelApplication application;
SysExcelWorkbooks workbooks;
SysExcelWorkbook workbook;
SysExcelWorksheets worksheets;
SysExcelWorksheet worksheet;
SysExcelCells cells;
SysExcelCell cell;

int row;
str contact;
int recordscount;
MYTABLE myTable;
System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
row = 1 ;

mailer.subject("MY subject");
mailer.fromAddress("MY_from@com");
mailer.htmlBody("MY_BODY");
mailer.tos().appendAddress("MY_to.com");

application = SysExcelApplication::construct();

workbooks = application.workbooks();
workbook = workbooks.add();
worksheets = workbook.worksheets();
worksheet = worksheets.itemFromNum(1);
cells = worksheet.cells();
//cells.range(‘A:A’).numberFormat(‘@’);
cell = cells.item(1,1);
cell.value("Field_I");
cell = cells.item(1,2);
cell.value("Field_II");

while select myTable
{
    row++;

    cell = cells.item(row, 1);
    cell.value(myTable.Field_I);
    cell = cells.item(row, 2);
    cell.value(myTable.Field_I);
}
application.visible(true);
application.save();
memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin::Begin);
```

I'm not able to save the file in temporary stream.

In AX2012 are not available the

```
SysMailerMessageBuilder mailer = new SysMailerMessageBuilder();;
var package = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(memoryStream)
```

//The below line used to attach excel file to email.
mailer.addAttachment(memoryStream, ‘MYFILE.xlsx’, ‘application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet’);

There is any way in Dynamics AX2012 to create an excel file and send the file to email (withouth saving in to the path).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can't you save in a temporary location? Have you seen `WinAPI::getTempPath()` (or `WinAPIServer`)? You can see how an XML is generated an saved in the path at `\Classes\DMFXmlGeneration\generationXML`

Comment: Thanks @Alex Kwitny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the @Alex Kwitny kind comment, I used this code:

```
#Properties
#AOT
#File
#define.io_rw("rw")
Filename                  filename;
str                       tempPath;
FileIOPermission          fileIOPermission;

if(_runOnService)
{
    fileIOPermission = new FileIOPermission('','r');
    fileIOPermission.assert();

    tempPath = WinAPIServer::getTempPath(); 

    CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
    filename = tempPath + _name + #xml;
}
else
{
   tempPath = WinAPI::getTempPath();

   filename = tempPath + _name + #xml;
}
```

tempPath = WinAPI::getTempPath();

tempPath = WinAPIServer::getTempPath();

Thanks all.